# Android Emulator Showing Chines character

Tags: android, rhodes

I have run my rhodes application in Android emulator. When i type characters in input field, i got chines character. How can i change lang setting please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Menu -> Settings -> Language & Keyboard -> Select Language (United State English) 

-> Text Setting -> Unchecked Chinese language, Japanese IME option
```

Answer (score 4):

I think it is Japanese characters :)

For changing any language or keyboard preferences go to settings (on main screen - menu button - settings), there find "language and keyboard" and change input language there.